# How to make it modular - Creating objects in Swift based on classnames defined in a plist?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, swift

How can I add objects based on classes/classnames loaded from a plist (as strings) using Swift? Is this even possible?

Here's what **didn't** work …

```
                var layer:NSClassFromString(layerClassNameString) = (NSClassFromString(layerClassNameString))()
```

I'd like to create a **modular structure** where I can add and remove layers of functionality defined as classes (≈in-app purchases) easily. Therefore these classes should be used for instantiation with the minimum amount of hard coding of switch statements and fixed classnames to make it easy to add new ones going forward.

Ideally I'd like to *just* add new the classes to the project and add their name to the plist. It would be great if the instantiation works across different classes of the same type/following the same protocol based on only one central definition (like the plist).

How can this kind of modularity be solved? Am I on the right track with using a plist as central point for this information?

Comment: Where would you put their methods? Like what happens when the user would like to use the in-app purchase?

Comment: all classes would conform to a protocol exposing a common set of methods.

Comment: I see... so all classes would act the same?

Comment: Yes. Of course they will do different kinds of processing and present different content, but the programming *interface* is always the same.

Comment: You can't use a constructed `Class` reference as type information even in ObjC. So the left-hand side of your declaration would need to reference the protocol that your dynamic classes conform to (in either language).

Comment: Also, you can't use in-app purchases to add executable code to an app. Since your plist will have to reference functionality that already exists in your app executable, you're probably better off abstracting the class names out of it: e.g. writing a `switch` statement that constructs different classes based in info loaded from the plist.

Comment: http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/06/05/instantiating-classes-by-name-in-swift/